# What are the general forms of mutually prime numbers?

Tags: arithmetic

One example I came across for two mutually prime numbers is $m(n + 1) + 1$ and $m(n + 1) - n$ for any two $m, n$ natural numbers. Are there any other such procedures for generation of mutually prime numbers?  Is there any reference where I can get these forms?

Comment: How about $mn$ and $mn+1$? More simply, $n$ and $n+1$.

Comment: Agree.Any two consecutive numbers are relatively prime.  But I am looking for non-trivial generation patterns like the one I gave above.

Comment: @SeethaRamaRajuSanapala What does "non-trivial" mean here? I think without a more precise notion of what you're looking for, this question is too broad.

Comment: I consider two successive numbers as trivial relatively prime numbers.  I am looking for generation methods like the one given in the question.